# How to share image from app with facebook sdk without native app?

Tags: java, android, facebook, share

How can i share image with facebook sdk without installed native app? I need make one share button, but i don't know how can i log in without LoginButton.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Login with Facebook without using LoginButton refere [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the [photo upload sample](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/sample-apps) from their website.